# How to make a level plot with ggplot with same look of the density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, density-plot

I like the look that the density plot of the ggplot view (Below). I wanna know how make a similar graph using a set of data interpoled (Data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8jbz10nnydsqw5/data.txt?dl=0). In other words, i wanna a graph with discrete contour and shaded colors.

I will appreciate your help

[image: Densityplot with ggplot]

For example:

The same plot is possible make with lattice package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

data=read.table("data.txt",header = T,sep = ";")
#discrete field
levelplot(var~long+lat,data = data,contour=T)
```

[image: Levelplot with Latice]

But, in ggplot i get this result when i apply the density plot:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=long,y=lat))+geom_density2d(aes(fill=var))+theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot wrong with ggplot]

I don't wanna make a density plot. I just wanna make a plot that look like the density plot in figure 1.

Comment: Please make a simple reproducible example that shows the "level plot" you currently have, including some example data within the question. This will make it much more likely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Ok. I will put more details in the standard post. I'm sorry my english.

Answer (score 1):

With `ggplot` I believe you require something like `ggplot(dat, aes(long, lat, fill = var)) + geom_raster()` and not the `geom_density2d` function. The default fill function is continuous as shown below. Others can point you to the functions to use discrete colors.

[image: default ggplot geom_raster]

For lattice, you have to provide the colors and the breakpoints to the `levelplot` function *and* to the `colorkey` argument list *and* to the `labels` argument list *within* the `colorkey` argument. It's not so obvious...but here is an example.

```
# dat <- read.delim(f, sep = ";")
  myCol <- brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu")[c(6,8:11)]
  breaks <- seq(min(dat$var), max(dat$var), len = 6)
  levelplot(var ~ long + lat, data = dat,
    at = breaks,
    col.regions = myCol,
    colorkey = list(col = myCol, at = breaks,
      labels = list(at = breaks, labels = round(breaks))
     )
   )
```

[image: level plot example with discrete steps]